# Why is math.sqrt() called a function? Since dot access is generally used for methods. What makes math.sqrt() a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, python-3.x

As an example: `math.sqrt()` is considered a *function* but, `"Lower".upper()` is known as the `.upper()` *method*.

Why is `math.sqrt` a function? Isn't the dot access indicative of methods?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/difference-between-a-method-and-a-function

Comment: The `.call_expr()` doesn't automatically mean that `call_expr` is a method. `.` is just python's attribute access operator and the attributes of objects are method objects. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) ([3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects)).

Comment: It's just a Python notation used for namespaces. Whether thing between is `.` or `::` ([like in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)) it's merely a design decision. Python is able to generalize all `.something` operations as _attribute access_, but that's just specific to Python language specification. Conceptually it's just a namespace mechanism.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `math` is a *module*<sup>*</sup>, not a *class*.

`sqrt` is a function defined inside the module `math`. You can access objects that have been defined in a module by normal dot `.` access on the module object. With modules though, no transformation of the function object occurs during that access, the object returned as is.
 
<sub>Specifically, [since functions are *descriptors*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods), their `__get__` isn't invoked when accessed through the module.</sub>

`upper` is a function that's defined inside the `str` *class*. When you invoke it on a `str` instance using dot access, it is *transformed* into a *method* which implicitly receives the instance as a first argument.
<sub>Specifically, when accessed through a class, a function object's  `__get__` is invoked which, in turn, transforms the function into a method type.</sub>

---

*Okay, I hate to do this, because it is confusing, but [modules are also classes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/types.html#types.ModuleType). They are special in that they don't do the transformation as described previously. Specifically, their getattribute function that is invoked when an attribute is requested, doesn't act like the default for classes.